# I have a function component and can't figure out how to import into a router, reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Slider component function, export default Slider.
In App.js I have

```
function App() {
return (
    <Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>} />
        <Route path='/blogs' element={<Blogs/>} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' element={<SignUp/>} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>
);
}
```

How would I go about having the component function run when the '/' Homepage loads?

This is the component function. Noob and having trouble finding the correct terms to search a proper documentation.

```
function Slider() {
    const messages = [
        "Around 920,000 cats and dogs were euthanized in animal shelters in 2020...",
        "Approximately 3.1 million dogs and 3.2 million cats enter animal shelters each year...",
        "Most pets are surrendered for adoption due to no fault of their own...",
        "If you'd like to take a leap towards adopting a pet, click on the green paw!"
    ];
    let i = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelector('#slides');

    function slide() {
        slides.innerHTML = messages[i];
        slides.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(next, 4000);
    }

    function next() {
        i++;
        if (i > messages.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        } else if (i === messages[3]) {
            setTimeout(10000);
        }
        slides.style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(slide, 2000);
    }
    return (
        Slider()
    );
}
export default Slider;
```

Comment: What is the component function you're referring to that you want to run when homepage loads? Your code sample is incomplete as it does not specify where `Router`, `Routers`, or `Route` come from, so it is harder to help you than it should be.

Comment: added the component function. The Routes are within a pages folder inside src folder. component folder is also within src folder

Comment: No I mean, where are you getting the `Router` variable from –– where is that imported from? What's your router package you're using?

Comment: react-router-dom

Comment: Haejinyi, You can import slider in Home component as route '/' loads home component. In componentDidMount of Home component, you can call the Slider.

Comment: Hard to say for sure because the sample is still incomplete but it seems like you should have the Slider code imported inside of the `<Home />` component so it will run when Home component is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the push towards a solution. just added it into github https://github.com/haejinyi0183/edens-pals-final

Comment: I have tried importing Slider from component into index.js(pages) with 'import Slider from "../components/Slider", but I'm stuck on where and how to call the function

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a good idea to recursively call `Slider()` by returning it. If you don't want to render anything, just return `null`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Slider component directly into the Home component because I'm assuming that this `#slides` element is on Home.